# How to create in flutter plugin for intent method using java

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

How to make intent call to any class in flutter plugin using java.
I am facing some errors **OnMethodCall** how to use intent inside call method in flutter plugin.
I searched on different platform for to get help about this problem.I am fail to find.

**My Imports :**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;

import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext;
import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity;
```

**OnMethodCall**

```
  @Override
  public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("getPlatformVersion")) {
      Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
      intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.RadioInfo");
     startActivity(intent);

    } else {
      result.notImplemented();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're a new contributor on StackOverflow so welcome. You mentioned in the initial post that you face some errors with the current implementation. Could you provide a summary/stack trace/debug logs, etc. for what happens when the current method is invoked?